# Change file type descriptions in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-types

I am using a certain file type (.QTZ) which I have successfully linked to an application. When I double click, the correct application starts. However, in Windows Explorer, it still says it is a "QTZ File".

How can I change that type description? I have found the "Default Programs" tab in the Control Panel, but it only lets me edit associations, not file types.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- Launch `regedit`.

  [image: step1]
- In `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, find your extension (you just have to type <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>). Example with `.ods` file:

  [image: step2]
- Look for the `Data` of the `(Default)` value (in my case, `opendocument.CalcDocument.1`, but in yours, something related to your application), and find this name in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` again, by typing the first letters. Example with `opendocument.CalcDocument.1`:

  [image: step3]
- Change the `Data` of the `(Default)` value to the description you want.

  [image: step4]
- Close regedit.

To see your changes appear, you can either reboot, or change the default association of some file by choosing **"Open with > Choose default program..."** (I couldn't find the proper method). Here is the result:

[image: result]

Comment: The (slightly) easier way to apply the changes is to kill the `explorer.exe` process using Task Manager, then File > Run new task and type `explorer` to reboot it.

Comment: I had the folder completely

Answer (score 6):

You can also use NirSoft's GUI-based [FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) utility. It's available for both [32-](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/filetypesman.zip) and [64-](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/filetypesman-x64.zip)bit systems.

- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or `Edit -> Find` to find your file type

  - Searches by any field available. See the **Edit File Type** dialog below.

    - Include the `.` for faster extension searches, such as `.script`
- Edit properties as desired.
- Toggle advanced options as desired.
- Click `OK`.

[image: FileTypesMan Edit dialog]

Pretty great, flexible, and very easy.

#### References

- NirSoft's [File Types Manager for Windows](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) page
- SevenForums' [Windows 7: File Extension Icon - Change Default Icon](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/57455-file-extension-icon-change-default-icon.html) tutorial

Comment: That's good, but sadly you can't edit more than one file at a time.

Comment: For some reason, I was trying to use this `FileTypesMan` and both `Type Name` and `Description` text fields were greyed out.   Ran as admin and also tried as `TrustedInstaller` (System).   Can't explain it.   I was setting up a new extension manually. 
 Win 10 LTSC 2021 (21H2)

Answer (score 2):

[The solution proposed by m4573r](https://superuser.com/a/474153/358766) used to be the only way to do this up to Windows XP but doesn't always work in Windows 7 if file extensions are first associated with a program from Explorer (when using "Open with >").

In such cases you might have to navigate to the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts
```

and change the `(Default)` value directly under your file extension registry key.

Comment: The registry key is there, but has no effect on Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

types.exe program.  https://ystr.github.io/types/
open the prg, select the ext, type new name, type descriptor changes when you close prg.

Answer (score 0):

Comment on the answer above from Oct 18 '19 by user1103198 (not enough reputation to comment properly):

To make Types.EXE even more convenient, save this code as Types.REG and *merge* the file into the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\Type]
@="Edit file type"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\Type\command]
@="\"C:\\Path\\Types\\Types.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Then open your Explorer context menu and follow the new item. (Tested on Win 8, not 7.)

Answer (score -2):

All my video file types were "MediaPlayerClassic-HC" files, regardless of the extensions (mov, mp4, wmv etc...). To avoid this, you should associate the files directly in MPC-HC "View/Options/Formats" instead of using "Open With" and "Choose Default" in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score -2):

After changes on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT , open task manager > processes, then select explorer.exe, end process button , go to applications tab, press new task button, write explorer.exe, and can see new filenames on type name.

Comment: In which way is this better than accepted answer?