# File type description disappears after changing default program in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I decided to set Atom as the default application for several file types, including `.log`, `.php`, and `.txt`. However, this has resulted in the file type description in File Explorer not showing in full anymore.

For example: `TXT File` instead of `Text Document`.

> [image: Image of file type descriptions]

If I change the default application for `.txt` back to Notepad, it will show as `Text Document` again, but I hate Notepad and want to continue using Atom.

Is it possible to restore the default descriptions without having to reset the default application? If not, how else can I modify the file type description?

Comment: How did you set it? Does Atom have an option to set itself as the default application?

Comment: I just right clicked the file, selected 'Properties', and then changed the app under 'Opens with' to Atom.

Comment: There is another way of setting the default application, and it is *possible* that it will be doing something different behind the scenes: in "All settings" go to "Apps", click "Default apps" on the left and then, down at the bottom, click "Choose default applications by file type" (it takes some time to list them all), scroll down to ".txt", and change it. You might want to change the default application for .txt back to Notepad before doing that.

Comment: Didn't make a difference, which is what I suspected.

Comment: In that case: [Change file type descriptions in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/q/474144/272824).

Comment: I had gone to **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\​Software\​Microsoft\​Windows\​CurrentVersion\​Explorer\​FileExts** in regedit to edit the values under the respective file extensions but to no avail.

Comment: I think that you would have to reboot the computer to make take effect, in case you haven't yet. Otherwise, there's [skia.heliou's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1005425/272824) to try.

Comment: I will try soon.

Comment: Restarting does not seem to work. I got File Types Manager but it shows the correct file description.

Comment: My next suggestion will be tedious to do and may also fail to work. With it reset so it show "Text Document", go through the registry searching for all occurrences of "Text Document" and note where they are. Change it to use Atom, and then go through all those locations to see which one (or more) is now wrong or missing. Edit it to the desired value. (Or perhaps export the registry values as you find them and then import them.)

Comment: I went through the registry editor to search for "Text Document" but got the exact same as before and after.

Comment: Anyway, is it possible for you to make the image show up on this page?